# How to stop subscribing store updates?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, store

I move user from component1 to component2 by `this.props.history.push`. When I am in component2 it looks like component1 is still mounted.

I tried everything as in similar problems with unsubscribe store.

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import {Animate} from 'react-animate-mount';
import {translateTexts} from "../App";
import store from "../../store";


class Component1 extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            texts: {
                computing: null
           },
        };
    }

    componentWillUnmount() {
        return store.subscribe(() => {
            console.log('unmount');
        })
    }

    componentWillMount() {
        store.subscribe(() => {
           translateTexts(this.state.texts),store.getState().translate.userLanguage).then((res) => {{
                this.setState({texts: res.data});
            });
        });


        axios.post(`/api/`)
            .then((res) => {
                this.setState({show: false});
                    setTimeout(() => {
                        window.location.href = '/storage/'+res.data.id
                    }, 600);        
             })
            .catch((err) => {
                this.props.history.push({
                    pathname: '/error/'+err.response.status,
                    state: { code: err.response.status }});
               });
            });


    render() {
         return (
             <div className="box">
                   Something
             </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Component1;
```

---

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import store from "../../store";
import {translateTexts} from "../App";

class Component2 extends Component {

     constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
        code : null,
        texts: {
            msg: null
           }
       };
    }

    componentWillMount() {
        this.setState( {
            code: this.props.location.state.code,
        });

        store.subscribe(() => {
           translateTexts(this.state.texts),store.getState().translate.userLanguage).then((res) => {{
                this.setState({texts: res.data});
            });
        });
    }

     render() {
        return (
            <div>
                Code: {this.state.code}
                <br></br>
                Message: <strong>{this.state.texts.msg}</strong>
             </div>
         );
    }
}

export default Component2;
```

After `componentWillUnmount` I would to stop subscribing `store` events in component, because now when my `store` updates I see log `unmount` in my console, so `Component1` is somehow mounted.
Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: A good practice is to keep your subscription open until the component unmounts. You can use `componentWillUnmount` to unsubscribe. You could also subscribe in the constructor, but I would suggest you don't do this as that's not what constructors are for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store subscribe should return the *unsubscribe* function which you can call at *componentWillUnmount* to successfully unsubscribe from the store.

you can define and store it in *state* directly in *componentWillMount*:

```
this.setState({
  unsubscribe: store.subscribe(() => {
       translateTexts(this.state.texts),store.getState().translate.userLanguage).then((res) => {{
            this.setState({texts: res.data});
        });
  });
});
```

and then call `unsubscribe` on *componentWillUnmount*

```
componentWillUnmount() {
  this.state.unsubscribe()
}
```

**Redux docs**: https://redux.js.org/api/store#subscribe

Comment: Thank you...  :-)

Answer (score 0):

If you're using React and Redux together, you really shouldn't be interacting with the store directly in your component.  Instead, you should be using the [official React-Redux library](https://react-redux.js.org), which handles all the subscription and store update process for you.  See the docs page on [Why Use React Redux?](https://react-redux.js.org/introduction/why-use-react-redux) for more details.